# Upgrade Indy9 to Indy10

Tags: delphi, indy

I want to upgrade my application from Indy 9 to 10 with Delphi 2007. 
In this thread there is a call to Indy9 TIdUDPBase.SendBuffer but this won't compile in Indy10 as the method parameter don't exists. The third parameter aBuffer is a var parameter and I didn't find any such method signature in Indy10.
Any alternative method to call ?

```
procedure TSenderThread.Execute;
var
  vTimeData: TTimeDataRecord;
  I: Integer;
  FElapsed: Int64;
  FTimerElappsed,
  vLastTimerElappsed: Int64;
begin
  vTimeData.Size := SizeOf(TTimeDataRecord);
  vTimeData.ClientCount := 1;
  Priority := tpHighest;
  FIdUDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
  FIdUDPClient.BroadcastEnabled := True;
  try
    while not (Terminated or Application.Terminated) do
    begin
      Sleep(1000);
      //Measure Time frame
      vLastTimerElappsed := FTimerElappsed;
      QueryPerformanceCounter(FTimerElappsed);
      FElapsed := ((FTimerElappsed-vLastTimerElappsed)*1000000) div FFrequency;
      vTimeData.TotalTimeFrame := FElapsed;
      if FRunning then
      begin
        FElapsed := ((FTimerElappsed-FStart)*1000000) div FFrequency;
        vTimeData.CurrentMessageTime := FElapsed;
      end
      else
        vTimeData.CurrentMessageTime := 0;
      //Copy Values
      vTimeData.AccumulatedTime := InterlockedExchange(TimeData.AccumulatedTime,0);
      vTimeData.MessageCount := InterlockedExchange(TimeData.MessageCount,0);
      for I := 0 to TimeClassMax do
        vTimeData.TimeClasses[I] := InterlockedExchange(TimeData.TimeClasses[I],0);

       // Calls procedure TIdUDPBase.SendBuffer(AHost: string; const APort: Integer; var ABuffer; const AByteCount: integer);
       // This is changed in Indy10, unable to compile  
      FIdUDPClient.SendBuffer('255.255.255.255', UIPerfPort, vTimeData, TimeData.Size);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FIdUDPClient);
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT:**
vTimeData is basically an array of integers.

```
  TTimeDataRecord = record
    Size: Integer; //Size of record structure is transfered and compared for safty reasons.
    ClientCount: Integer;
    AccumulatedTime: Integer; //This is the accumulated time busy in microseconds
    CurrentMessageTime: Integer; //This is the time the current message has been processed. If several computers report a high value at the same time it indicates a freeze!
    TotalTimeFrame: Integer; //This is the total time measured in microseconds
    MessageCount: Integer;
    TimeClasses: array [0..TimeClassMax] of Integer;
  end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a method with same name

```
procedure TIdUDPClient.SendBuffer(const AHost: string; const APort: TIdPort;
  const ABuffer: TIdBytes);
```

Instead of an untyped buffer it expects an array of bytes. What is your data like? You just need to write your data as an array of bytes. Something like:

```
var
 Buffer: TIdBytes;
begin
 SetLength(Buffer, YourSizeOfData);
 Move(YourData, Buffer[0], YourSizeOfData);
 FIdUDPClient.SendBuffer('255.255.255.255', UIPerfPort, Buffer);
end;
```

But as I said it depends on the type of the data. The approach is ok however.

EDIT:

Now that I can see that you have a record you have two options:

Just move the whole record to array of bytes.

```
Move(@aRecord, Buffer[0], (6 + TimeClassMax) * SizeOf(Integer));
```

Have a CopyToBytes method in your record that does the actual copy. More general I guess.

```
TTimeDataRecord = record
  Size: Integer; //Size of record structure is transfered and compared for safty reasons.
  ClientCount: Integer;
  AccumulatedTime: Integer; //This is the accumulated time busy in microseconds
  CurrentMessageTime: Integer; //This is the time the current message has been  processed. If several computers report a high value at the same time it indicates a freeze!
  TotalTimeFrame: Integer; //This is the total time measured in microseconds
  MessageCount: Integer;
  TimeClasses: array [0..TimeClassMax] of Integer;
  procedure CopyToBytes(var Buffer: TIdBytes);
end
```

Implementation of the CopyToBytes

```
procedure TTimeDataRecord.CopyToBytes(var Buffer: TIdBytes);
begin
  // copy the data however you see fit
end;
```

Comment: It is a record, see the update but it contains only integers. Maybe I can typecast it to TIdBytes or must I copy it to another buffer of type TIdBytes ?

Comment: FYI, Indy 10 has RawToBytes() and BytesToRaw() functions for converting TIdBytes values from/to raw memory blocks.